# SmartSheet - I am trying to get access token using Oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, access-token, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am trying to integrate Power Automate (Workflow service) with SmartSheet using OAuth 2.0

I have got the auth code successfully and when I finally try to get the token, it throws the message - 'You are not authorized to perform this action.' with error code 1004

I tried in Postman with the same result.
[image: Flow to SmartSheet]

Comment: Putting a `client_id` and `client_secret` in your post is not a good idea.

Comment: This is just a POC I am trying to do. Thanks @RyanWilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're specifying all 5 values via the Request **Header**. Only `Content-Type` is specified via the Header -- the other four parameters (`client_id`, `client_secret`, `code`, and `grant_type`) should be specified via the query string. You're getting the *not authorized* error because Smartsheet is looking for the value of `client_id` etc. in the query string but not finding it there.

For example, here are screenshots from Postman that show setting `Content-Type` via the Headers and the other four parameters via the Params:

[image: Headers in Postman request]

[image]

Comment: Excellent - happy to help!